# Membership code-first - Add FK to IdentityRole without extending class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

As the title says, I'd like to add a FK to Membership's IdentityRole without extending/deriving class:

I have:

```
 public class ApiController
    {
    [Key]
    public int ApiControllerId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

I would like to add

```
public ICollection<ApiController> Controllers { get; set; }
```

to Membership's IdentityRole class so EF creates a many-many relationship table (ie ApiControllerRoles)

I have done my homework and I know how to do this (normally) except I don't actually have class definition for IdentityRole in my project. Any idea how I could add this foreign key without the class definition or better yet, how I could go about getting a copy of this class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `ApplicationRole` Entity base on `IdentityRole`

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
      ...
      public ICollection<ApiController> Controllers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
      public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection") {}
}

public class ApiController
{
        [Key]
        public int ApiControllerId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but deriving off IdentityRole will create a discriminator column which seems redundant. I'm not looking to extend, I'm looking to modify existing class. Thanks

Comment: It will not create a discriminator column. IdentityRole will not be included in dbContext, instead its the extended class